# Remove failed Solve[] attempts

Tags: equation-solving, syntax

I can't figure how to replace a failed evaluation with a null value.

I am very new to Mathematica.

I have an equation that are being processed using the `Solve[]` function and I then need to forward the results to other steps in my process. Some of the equations don't have solutions. This is desired and I want to eliminate those possibilities.

After generating a list with all the solutions I process that list like this:

```
SillySyntax[Rule_] = Quiet[x /. Rule];
Quiet[Curve = Table[SillySyntax[Curves[[i]]], {i, 5}]]
```

This works fine, but sometimes when errors such as the following happen they break my workflow by not putting a null in there. Instead leaving a ghost of an equation. This is not desired because I know *a priori* that these errors mean that the system is not physical. How can I remove these aberrations and ensure that `SillySyntax`  will output only numbers or empties.

```
Greater::nord: "Invalid comparison with 0.347148 -1.5103810834566311` I"
```

Comment: could you give an example of the output of `Solve` and these "ghost"-functions?

Comment: Try `Quiet` in combination with [Check](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Check.html)

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure your error message comes from something different. Anyway, what happens if you use for instance such a solve function?

```
solveMe[z_] := 
 Module[
  {solution = Solve[x^2 + y^2 == z^2 && y > x > 0, {x, y}, Integers]},
  If[solution =!= {},
    {x, y} /. solution,
    solution
  ]
]
```

If the solution is empty, it just returns the `{}`. Otherwise, it extracts the numbers of the solution. Therefore:

```
Table[solveMe[z],{z,30}]
(*
{{},{},{},{},{{3,4}},{},{},{},{},{{6,8}},{},{},{{5,12}},{},{{9,12}},
{},{{8,15}},{},{},{{12,16}},{},{},{},{},{{7,24},{15,20}},{{10,24}},{},
{},{{20,21}},{{18,24}}}
*)
```

Since you mentioned `Quiet`: If you want a function which returns something else when a message is generated, you can use `Check`.

```
f[e_] := Quiet[Check[1/e, "Hola seniorita"]]
f[1]
f[0]

(*
  1
  "Hola seniorita"
*)
```

Here we catch the message that is generated when we divide by 0 and return a different result.

Comment: The problem is that the solution is not empty, the Solve[] routine fails, with some error I don't want to deal with. I will try this and let you know, thanks.

Comment: @Mikhail The `Check` will help you. Btw, you never want to use `Rule` as variable name! It's an important built-in function!

Comment: I know halirutan wanted to show the empty solutions in this case, but in the normal case, where only the actual solutions are wanted, I remind readers that the empty solutions can be removed from the output of `Table[...]` by prefixing `Table[...]` with `Join@@`.